# Python in worker has different version: environment variables are set correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a Python script on a Jupyter notebook on Linux Mint.

The code is hardly important but here it is (it's a tutorial for graphframes):

```py
import pandas
import pyspark

from functools import reduce
from graphframes import *
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, when
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

vertices = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("a", "Alice", 34),
        ("b", "Bob", 36),
        ("c", "Charlie", 30),
        ("d", "David", 29),
        ("e", "Esther", 32),
        ("f", "Fanny", 36),
        ("g", "Gabby", 60),
    ],
    ["id", "name", "age"],
)

edges = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("a", "b", "friend"),
        ("b", "c", "follow"),
        ("c", "b", "follow"),
        ("f", "c", "follow"),
        ("e", "f", "follow"),
        ("e", "d", "friend"),
        ("d", "a", "friend"),
        ("a", "e", "friend"),
    ],
    ["src", "dst", "relationship"],
)

g = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)

display(g.inDegrees.toPandas())
```

The last line is the line causing trouble, it gives the following error:

```
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

These two variables **are** correctly set:

```sh
printenv PYSPARK_PYTHON
-> /usr/bin/python3
printenv PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON
-> /usr/bin/python3
```

I also added them to my `spark-env.sh` file as so:

```sh
# This file is sourced when running various Spark programs.
# Copy it as spark-env.sh and edit that to configure Spark for your site.

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3       
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

But the error persists, where else could I have to update these variables?

**Edits**

```
python --version
Python 3.7.4

pip3 list | grep jupyter
jupyter               1.0.0      
jupyter-client        5.3.4      
jupyter-console       6.0.0      
jupyter-core          4.6.1      
jupyterlab            1.1.4      
jupyterlab-server     1.0.6     

pip3 list | grep pyspark
pyspark               2.4.4
```

Comment: @RMPR how can I check which version is being called?

Comment: @RMPR I get this: `Python 3.7.4`

Comment: @RMPR I'll add them to my question

Comment: @RMPR Guess I'm boned then, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @RMPR I also have Python 2 installed on my system, could I maybe remove it and all my pip modules?

Comment: @RMPR I get this `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is more likely conflicting versions of python. Set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to `/usr/bin/python`.
Alternatively you can use [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

```sh
cd ~
python3 -m venv spark_test
cd spark_test
source ./bin/activate
pip3 install jupyterlab pyspark graphframes
jupyter notebook
```

You must put the jupyter file inside your newly created folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more likely to be conflicting versions of Python.
Set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to `/usr/bin/python`.
Alternatively, you can use a different environment:

```bash
conda create --name foo python=3.6

source activate foo

python -m pip install --user jupyter

conda activate foo

jupyter notebook
```